# Nested Object not showing the component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mantine

Strangely, I have `<Avatar>` that works with single object parse using `.map`

```js
<Flex>
  <div></div>
  {studentsjson.map((thr) => (
    <Avatar color="red" key={thr.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
      {thr.Name}
    </Avatar>
  ))}
</Flex>
```

However, below does not work

```js
{
  teacher.map((thr) =>
    thr.students.map((stu) => {
      <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
        {stu.studentName}
      </Avatar>;
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Remove the curly brace characters at `stu=>{` & `})))`

Comment: If you add `{` in your function, you have to add the `return` keyword. 
e.g 1: `() => { /* you should add return key word*/}`  
e.g 2: `() => // no need of return key word`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the callback argument of the nested `.map` returns nothing. Hence, nothing can be expected to render. This can be fixed by removing the curly braces to perform an "implicit return".

I have a feeling you'll want to use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as well; e.g.

```
{
  teachers.flatMap(
      teacher =>
          teacher.students.map(
               student =>
                   <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
                     {stu.studentName}
                   </Avatar>
          )
      )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second block of code, the problem is that you are only looping through `students` creating `<Avatar/>`s but nothing is returned, you either have to use

implicit return :

```js
teacher.map((thr) =>
  thr.students.map((stu) => (
    <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
      {stu.studentName}
    </Avatar>
  ))
)
```

or explicit return :

```js
teacher.map((thr) =>
  thr.students.map((stu) => {
    return (
      <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
        {stu.studentName}
      </Avatar>
    )
  })
)
```

to return an non empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Following place is where you are making mistake.

```js
{
teacher.map((thr) =>
  thr.students.map((stu) => { // this map is not returning anything
    <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
      {stu.studentName}
    </Avatar>;
  })
)
}
```

add a return statement or remove `{` curly braces.

```js
{
teacher.map((thr) =>
  thr.students.map((stu) => (
    <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
      {stu.studentName}
    </Avatar>
  ))
)
}
```